# Yesterdays date in "MMdd", and specific output folder selection depending on date

Tags: sorting, date, powershell, video, ffmpeg

so im trying to manage CCTV footage,
and so far i've come up with this code in powershell:

Gets yesterdays date in MMdd (todays version will be 0516), -> selects all files that begin with that -> compresses them using ffmpeg -> moves to another folder  -> deletes source fules

```
$a = get-date -format "MMdd"
$b = 1
$c = $a - $b
$d = $c.ToString("0000")
$inProcessPath = "sourcepath"
$oldVideos = Get-ChildItem -Include @("$d *") -Path $inProcessPath -Recurse;

Set-Location -Path 'D:\ffmpeg\bin';

foreach ($oldVideo in $oldVideos) {
    $newVideo = [io.path]::ChangeExtension($oldVideo.FullName, '.avi')


    $ArgumentList = '-i "{0}" -b 200000 "{1}"' -f $oldVideo, $newVideo;


    Start-Process -FilePath "D:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -ArgumentList $ArgumentList -Wait -NoNewWindow;
}

Robocopy D:\ffmpeg\bin\ntv D:\newpaths "$d *.avi" /mov

get-childitem "sourcepath" -include "$d *.mp4" -recurse | foreach ($_) {remove-item $_.fullname}
```

But, during the testing stage I realised that my implementation wont work when there is a month switch, since from lets say 0601 it wont produce 0531, but 0600.

Also I need the converted files to be moved to a directory according to current Months, so if i have folder May,June, etc. And i need files that start with 05 go to May folder, and so on.

Can someone help my accomplish my task, in code or in advice

My programming knowledge is not enough to solve this issue.

The main goal is automation

---

For the first part courtesy to @dotnetom
This worked:

```
$d = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("MMdd")
```

For the second part i've comeup with this

```
    $a = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("MMMM")

Robocopy D:\Main\AdWords\ffmpeg\bin\ntv "D:\path\$a" "$d *.avi" /mov
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the previous day you can use function `AddDays` to get yesterday's date, and then format it according to your needs:

```
$d = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("MMdd")
```

If we break this code down, the components are:

```
$currentDay = get-date                 # current day
$yesterday = $currentDay.AddDays(-1)   # yesterday
$formattedYesterday = $yesterday.ToString("MMdd")  #yesterday formatted to MMdd
```

Comment: This does it, and using your code i did the same for second part and it worked

$a = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("MMMM")
thank you